# I want transform .wav in a list

Tags: python-3.x, audio, scipy, wav

I am getting this error when trying to transform `.wav`s in a list:

> VALUEERROR: total size of  new array must be unchanged

This is my code:

```
#library
import numpy as np
import scipy.io.wavfile as wave

rate, data= wave.read('sinalAtrasado_0.wav')
```

The parameters are `2channels, sampwidth 2 framerate 44100 none compressed`.

Comment: It would help if you could post the WAV file somewhere.  Also, which version of scipy are you using?  To find the version, run `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`

Comment: version 0.16.0 http://freewavesamples.com/casio-cz-5000-human-voice-c4

Comment: Using scipy 0.16.1 (which doesn't have any changes to the io module relative to 0.16.0), I get a warning when I read that file (`WavFileWarning: Chunk (non-data) not understood, skipping it.`), but the operation completes and the data appears to be OK.  I can also read it using `wavio` (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wavio/) with no warnings, and get the same data as returned by `scipy.io.wavfile.read`.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xpjxuo7nmqjqzdp/sinalAtrasado_0.wav?dl=0

Comment: i generated this file, with wav i wanted to add a Time of silence in the beggining of the audio.

Comment: Thanks.  I get the same error as you when I read it with `scipy.io.wavfile.read`: `ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged`.   I *can* read it with `wavio.read` (which is just a wrapper of the Python `wave` module).

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot, but i couldnt install wavio with anaconda.